# Is LCM of rationals used in higher math?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers, least-common-multiple

I read in this school book, an algorithm to find the LCM of rationals. It goes in the following manner. $[\frac{a}{b}, \frac{c}{d}]=\frac{[a,c]}{(b,d)}$.

If you inspect as to why the formula is given so you will realise that this formula gives the smallest positive rational which is an integral multiple of both $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$.

For example, $[\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}]=\frac{3}{2}$. Where, $\frac{3}{2}=3(\frac{1}{2})=2(\frac{3}{4})$.

Now, what is puzzling me is the idea of LCM. Because I was of the opinion that this is a concept only defined on integer, but here they define it for rational numbers. So, is this a universally accepted formula or was it just something the person who wrote this book put in?

I just realised that someone has already asked a question previously questioning the logic behind this formula. Well, that is not my question. I wish to know whether this formula is actually relevant in higher mathematics.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Not completely. I see someone has asked a question about the logic behind the formula, my question is about its relevance and whether it is actually used in higher mathematics

Comment: It's used in Number theory.

Comment: Yes, it is actually used more generally over commutative rings, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#The_LCM_in_commutative_rings).